# Serve 200 without reading the request

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, http, io

I have a system where

- Server receives large files from clients
- Files are unused and deleted immediately
- Clients cannot be updated to stop sending files
- There are a known number of clients (required number of threads is constant)
- The server must be Windows/IIS VMs

How do I minimize this system's footprint?  My only ideas occur after the request has been parsed and loaded by IIS, but I would ideally like a solution that does not read the large file (blocking the networking card).  Is there a way to block requests in Windows or IIS while still returning 200s?

Comment: Turn off the server.

Comment: All you provide are really awkward limitations that you impose upon yourself preventing you from fixing the issue.  If you know the clients, get their admin to stop them or block them at the firewall level.

Comment: No you can't do that. Solve the problem by it's source. If you really can't all you can do is block the IPs of the abusive clients entirely. That you're willing to come up with such a complicated solution while blocking seems the logical conclusion leads me to believe that there's something here you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP client will write its request to the server, and then read the reply. You could in theory write the reply as soon as the connection opens or as soon as you've read the beginning of the request, but I would be very surprised if your client would read that and react to it before it has sent all its data, it might even freeze something. In short, if you want the client to get its "200" reply, you can't stop it from writing the request that it expects a reply to. (If you didn't care about the client getting its 200 reply you could turn off your server or break off the TCP connection).

If you cannot modify the clients, all you can do is to make the server discard the data as efficiently as possible (not writing it to a file), and to upgrade the connectivity if you have bandwidth problems (you didn't say what your specific problem is, only that you want to minimize the system's footprint).